# CSS on ul/li not responding

Tags: css, list, html, tabs, html-lists

I added a wordpress widget to handle the 3 tabs on the sidebar for Events, Blog and Twitter.

http://islands.kellykruschel.com/ (right side, above Our Partners).

I am trying to make the width:95px and height:45px

I have placed the width/height on the li but nothing responds. The ul will respond to the height but that doesn't help me much.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it's too specific to your site, and unlikely to help any future visitors.  The best questions have a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code *directly* into the question. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.style1 ul.tabbernav li {display: inline-block;}
```

Or, if you like floats:

```
.style1 ul.tabbernav li {float: left;}
```

It appears though that you want something else. Normally I don't fix people's layout, but just for once, I suppose. Add these styles:

```
.style1 ul.tabbernav li {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
line-height: 45px;
}

ul.tabbernav li {
height: auto;
}
.style1 ul.tabbernav li a, .style1 ul.tabbernav li.tabberactive a {
background-color: transparent
}
.style1 ul.tabbernav {
background: #095c87;
}
```

Result:

[image: result of proposed code]

Comment: The float forces display to computer to block, so float: left is sufficient.

Comment: Clever! by setting the background color on ul, you got around finding the magic width for the li elements!

Comment: I am not able to have the ul background color the same for all three tabs but you pointed me in the right direction. Thanks! :)